# How to detect whether the current file might contains a long line?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. I want to disable some plugins when the current file is a production file, i.e. it is compacted into < 10 lines but each line contains >1000 columns. I'm using NeoVim so I prefer script written in Lua, but VimScript is also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the search command to search for the beginning of a line followed by a number of characters. If you do

`/^.\{30}`

It will search for the beginning of a line followed by 30 characters, so for lines containing at least 30 characters. You can change the number to fit your needs.

Comment: But I want to use `if` statement to detect it?

Comment: @Kindred You can use :%s/^.\{30}//n That will count the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use combination of `strwidth` and `getfsize` to achieve my goal:

```lua
is_supported = function ()
  if vim.fn.strwidth(vim.fn.getline('.')) > 300
    or vim.fn.getfsize(vim.fn.expand("%")) > 1024 * 1024 then
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need a function. In just about any programming language you can assign the result of an expression directly to a variable, e.g. `foo = bar or baz`. A _boolean_ expression like this will assign either 'true' or 'false' (or '1' or '0' in some langauges). Since you want to assign 'false' if your expression evaluates to 'true', you can 'not' the whole thing: `foo = not (bar or baz)` (Alternatively, you could invert the boolean logic by inverting the three operators: both `>` to `<=` and `or` to `and`.)